# Updating table based on user input

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sql-update

I created a table with the following details:

```
myStr2 = "CREATE TABLE Lecturers (lec_no VARCHAR(3), name VARCHAR(30), email VARCHAR(30), PRIMARY KEY(lec_no))"
```

I then created a function that would be able to update the table.

```
def update_lecturer(self, field_to_update, value_to_set, lec_no):
           self.field_to_update = field_to_update
           self.value_to_set = value_to_set
           self.lec_no = lec_no
           self.myCursor.execute("UPDATE Lecturers SET field_to_update = :field_to_update WHERE lec_no =:lec_no",{'field_to_update':self.field_to_update,'value_to_set':self.value_to_set,'lec_no':self.lec_no})
```

The table is updated based on the user input:

```
field_to_update = input("Field update:")
value_to_set = input("Value to set:")
lec_no = input("Lec_no:")
```

where the field_to_update can be name or email, the value_to_set can be either new value of name or the new value of email.The lec_no is the id of the lecturer whose details we would like to change.

However when I run the my code I get the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: field_to_update
```

I know there is no such column as field_to_update in my table but how can I set the column to be updated based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

In your last line you should replace the field_to_update with your input and the updated values.

```
self.myCursor.execute("UPDATE Lecturers SET :field_to_update = :value_to_set ...
```

(you missed a colon and the actual `value_to_set`)

Comment: when I do this I get an error....sqlite3.OperationalError: near ":field_to_update": syntax error

Comment: print the query string to your console and verify that you query is correctly generated. I assume the bug is within the string generation and not with your sqlite db.

Answer (score 0):

I concatenated the variable field_to_update in the update statement then added question marks to represent the other two variables and it worked. Here is my code:

```
def update_lecturer(self, field_to_update, value_to_set, lec_no):
           self.field_to_update = field_to_update
           self.value_to_set = value_to_set
           self.lec_no = lec_no
           self.myCursor.execute("UPDATE Lecturers SET "+self.field_to_update+" = (?) WHERE lec_no = (?)",(self.value_to_set,self.lec_no))       

           self.myConnection.commit()
```